# Error 'gem install rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to give command in (CMD) as my command is : 
gem install rails

but it's giving error. 
i tested ruby -v and it gave a result, but cannot install rails !!

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `chcp 1252` then install the gem. This will change the encoding of the current command prompt.